# Integral of the square of the normal distribution.

Tags: calculus, integration

Does someone know what the integral of the square of the normal distribution with standard deviation sigma over the range $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by square of the normal distribution? If you mean the square of the density function, a change of variable will do it.

Comment: Are you squaring the pdf as Andre guesses or are you squaring the random variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are squaring the PDF...

\begin{align*}
 & \phantom{=}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)\right)^{2}dx\\
 & =\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\right)dx\\
 & =\frac{\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sigma^{2}\pi}\\
 & =\frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I wanted to square the PDF (not the random variable).  So this answer is awesome. Thanks!