# Confusion over marginalising out probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have seen the probability equation below somewhere and I'm reasoning that it holds because the integral marginalises out $a$ leaving $p(c|s)$

$$ p(c|s) = \int p(a|s) \cdot p(c,a|s) \  da $$

where all the probabilities are PDFs.

I am wondering then whether the following is also true given that when you marginalise out $a$ then you are also left with $p(c|s)$ :

$$ p(c|s) = \int p(a) \  \ \  \cdot p(c,a|s) \  da $$

**If this is also true**, then I am left wondering how to (intuitively) reason that:

$$ \int p(a|s) \cdot p(c,a|s) \  da = \int p(a)  \cdot p(c,a|s) \  da $$

*Note: I don't come from a statistics background so apologies if the answer is obvious.*

Second Edit: I got the first equation from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05533.pdf) which is the first equation in **Section 2.3** but replacing $s'$ with $c$ and replacing $\pi(a|s)$ for $p(a|s)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89311/discussion-on-question-by-mellow-confusion-over-marginalising-out-probability).

Comment: (There is some relevant discussion on the comments that has been archived in the chat. Please take note of it when answering the question.)

Comment: For the record, I respectfully disagree that it wasn't clear what was being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second expression seems to suggest (in conjunction with the first) that:

$$\int p(a|s) \cdot p((c,a)|s) \  da = \int p(a) \cdot p((c,a)|s) \  da $$

Now let $c=a$ (they are the same event). Then you get:

$$\int  p(a|s)^2 \  da = \int p(a) \cdot p(a|s) \  da $$

This seems to not be true in general. Let's say for example that $a$ is normal and conditional on $s$, it becomes normal with a different mean. It's easy to see from this answer: [Integral of the square of the normal distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512879/integral-of-the-square-of-the-normal-distribution) that the two sides will not be the same.

---

EDIT: Let's clarify some terminology.

Let's call the random variables $A$ and $S$. The $a$ is the event $A=a$ and $a|s$ is the event $A=a$ conditional on $S=s$ This is equivalent to the event $A=a \cap S=s$ in the space $S=s$ see here for more details:
[No such thing as conditional events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102157/no-such-thing-as-conditional-events). There is some abuse of notation here in terms of $a$ being interpreted as a scalar within the context of the integrals (otherwise, $da$ wouldn't make sense), but apart from that, everything is well-defined.

Building on this, another way to see why your second expression is wrong. You had:

$$ p(c|s) = \int p(a) \  \ \  \cdot p((c,a)|s) \  da $$

Let $a' = a|s$ since $a'$ and $a$ have the same domain (just their densities at those points in the domain are potentially different) so it doesn't matter which of them we integrate over we get:

$$ p(c|s) = \int p(a) \  \ \  \cdot p(c|s ,a') \  da' $$

You can see that this is only true if $a'=a$. Another point is that the event $A=a$ is not even in the same probability space as $C=c \& A=a | S=s$. So those two probabilities are apples to oranges and it's probably problematic to multiply them.

Comment: Just to clarify. In my original post, which of the first two equations is correct?

Comment: I think the first one is correct and the second one isn't

Comment: If we're talking about the universe where $s$ has happened, we have to stay in that universe.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused because I thought that you can always add variables as long as you integrate them out.  Can we write $p(c|s) = \int p(c,a|s) da$?

Comment: That looks right, everything is conditional on $s$. In your second expression, you selectively conditioned on $s$.

Comment: Ah okay so the take away point is that you can always add variables and integrate them out AS LONG AS it the variables you add are conditioned  on whatever is conditioned on in the expression. Does that sound about right?

Comment: I think so. So something like (if you want to add $b$ and integrate it out as well) - $$p(c|s) = \int p(b|s) \int  p(a|s)p(c,a, b|s) \  da \ db$$

Comment: See my edit. Added another way to look at it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've got it. Wish I could +1 your answer but I don't currently have the threshold reputation points for that privilege yet. Will add the +1 later once I've reached and I remember.

Comment: FYI, there is such thing as a random variable $a|s$, hence the subsequent paragraph falls.

Comment: $a|s$ is $a$ in a universe where $s$ has taken place. In any case, you can only consider it within the PDF's and not call it $a'$ if you like the the argument still holds.

Comment: $p(a,c|s) = p(a|s, c|s)$ $a$ is an event, not a r.v

Comment: If $a$ and $s$ are events, what is $da$? And $p(a|s,c|s)$ is even worse... Sorry but you are just misleading the OP, on a topic which is notoriously badly taught and which needs to be especially rigorously explained.