# No such thing as conditional events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I recently answered a question ([Confusion over marginalising out probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098815/confusion-over-marginalising-out-probability/3098957#3098957)) on conditional probability and one particular bit of terminology I used seems to have evoked a visceral reaction in some people. However, I still can't see what's wrong with it. Let's say there are three events, $A$, $B$ and $C$. It is pretty clear what is meant when we say $P(A,B|C)$. And it is also clear what we mean when we say $P(A|C)$ and $P(B|C)$. In this sense, I think of $A|C$ as a conditional event and $P(A|C)$ as its probability. Taking this further, I can write:

$$P(A,B|C) = P(A|C,B|C)$$

But some people seem to think there is no such thing as a conditional event. My problem with this statement is that probabilities are always defined on events. If there is no such thing as a conditional event, how can there be a conditional probability? And if there indeed is "no such thing", what exactly prevents me from defining it? I just want to understand where that user was coming from and what I might be missing.

Comment: The notation $P(A \mid B)$ is probably flawed, I would better use (as Chung does) $P_B(A).$

Comment: Interesting. I've actually seen $P(A|B)$ used a lot.

Comment: It is the most common notation, but it has this flaws, it kind of make the idea that $A\mid B$ makes sense as an end in itself. But $A \mid B$ _really_ means nothings. What you are doing is constructing a _new_ probability measure on the trace space over $B$ and it is denoted by $A \mapsto P(A \mid B),$ so I am saying, as Kai Lai Chung taught me, that $P_B(A)$ is better notation.

Comment: $A\mid B$ is not an event in the sense that $A\cap B$ is an event.  As others have explained, it can be interpreted as an event in a different space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your notation but I can also see where others are coming from when they object to calling $A|B$ an event.

If $A$ and $B$ are events in some probability space $\Omega$, we can define the conditional probability $P(A|B)$.  If we want to interpret $A|B$ itself as an event, then it would have to be as the event $A \cap B$ in the space $B$, *not* in the original probability space $\Omega$. When people say $A|B$ is not an event, they probably mean that it's not an event in $\Omega$.

Now, when you write a joint probability expression like $P(A|C, B|C)$, it makes sense because both of the individual $A|C$ and $B|C$ can be interpreted as events on the space $C$.  However, we cannot write something like $P(A|C, B|D)$, because now we have 2 events in two different probability spaces $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Still confused about this scenario - Let's say $C$ is correlated with $A$ and $D$ is correlated with $B$. All other pairs of events are independent. Don't we then need some notion of $P(A|C, B|D)$? Let's say $C$ is the event that it snows in NY and $D$ the event that it snows in Seattle. $A$ is the event that there are more than $a$ accidents in NY and $B$ is the event that there are more than $b$ accidents in Seattle. In this context, don't we need something like $P(A|C, B|D)$? Or is it more apt to say $P(A \cap C, B \cap D)$